# why local object is not destroying when coming out of add() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, object, memory-management

```
class Demo:  
    def __init__(self,l=[]):  
        self.l=l  
    def add(self,x):  
        t=Demo()  
        t.l.append(x)  
        print(t.l)

o1=Demo()  
o2=Demo()  
o1.add(1)  
o2.add(2)
```

output:

```
[1]  
[1,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Demo:
    def __init__(self, l=[]):
        self.l = l[:]

    def add(self, x):
        t = Demo()
        t.l.append(x)
        print(t.l)


o1 = Demo()
o2 = Demo()
o1.add(1)
o2.add(2)
```

Lists in Python are a bit of a weird thing. The modification above allows you to work with a new list

Comment: Or `def __init__(self, l=None): self.l = l or []`.

Comment: Lists aren't a "weird thing" and the behavior here applies to all types not just lists as default arguments

Answer (score 0):

This is the mutable default parameter pitfall.

```
def __init__(self,l=[]):
```

The empty list object is created at module level and common to all `Demo` instances.

See ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).